# Non animating view inside a Animating view android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a frame layout that fills the phone area (fill_parent). Also a imageView kept inside the frame layout centreInParent.

Now I am using scale animation to reduce the size of frame layout. But I don't want the imageView to reduce the size, besides I want to move the imageView centre to the frame layout with respect to its scaling.

How can I achieve this ?

my xml:

```
<FrameLayout 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"  >
       <ImageView 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:gravity="center"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true" 

          android:src="@drawable/bglogo"/>  

    </FrameLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just make ImageView Independent from the frame layout for which you have applied animation

Comment: That is the logic. But I don't know how we can achieve this using codes

Comment: Simply Remove Image View From Your FrameLayout and make it independent ; please post your xml code

Comment: I have added my xml. But I guess If I remove the ImageView from the Frame Layout I have to apply seperate animation for it. Right ?

Comment: does it required to reset the size of imageview after Animation..?

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Layout to following way

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"  >

</FrameLayout>
<ImageView 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
      android:src="@drawable/bglogo"/>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Only the frameLayout undergoes scale animation but the image view is fixed

Comment: After Animation Change the Parameters for ImageView as necessary